# Do we know if dogs are asymptomatic transmiters of sars-cov-2?

Tags: virology, coronavirus, epidemiology, infectious-diseases

Dogs do not use mask when going for a walk nor they observe the security distance. On the contrary, they frequently join their noses, and put their noses where other dogs had put them before or had urinated. So, as they are our pets, it is important to know if they can be asymptomatic transmiters of sars-cov-2. Do we know it? At least, have we tested asymtomatic pets of people infected with sars-cov-2?

Comment: Related, and easier to check: do we know if some data associated to sars-cov-2 is higher among people with dogs at home?

Comment: It is the opposite, if the human is not infected then the probability that the pet (cat or dog) is positive is very low. To prove the infection they check that the animal is positive for > 4 days, because they are asymptomatic. If they'd find high viral load they would tell it (ie. very low viral load thus animals pets are not contagious). In contrary minks had symptoms and contaminated each other, same for a few tigers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be too early to tell.

Testing of dogs in Wuhan found no infected dogs
"487 dogs including 90 beagle dogs, 147 pet dogs and 250 street dogs during the outbreak of SARS‐CoV‐2 were also tested serological negative."
from https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/tbed.13577

This article mentions deliberate infection of five dogs. on this very small sample they suggest that dogs are not likely to become carriers.

"Coronavirus can infect cats - dogs, not so much."
https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00984-8

found by searching "dog" on LitCovid at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/coronavirus/

Comment: I am assembling sources there https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/92436/what-are-the-implications-of-tigers-being-susceptible-to-covid-19/92458#92458

Comment: I saw your sources too late. LitCovid is a great collection of papers too.